# Derivative of $x(x+2)^3$ in factored form don't see it

Tags: derivatives, factoring

Studying for a big test trying to do the derivative of $x(x+2)^3$.

I did the product rule and got $3x(x+2)^2 + (x+2)^3$. Pretty standard stuff.

I got half credit and was told to simplify it like this:

[Teacher's Simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACtT9.png)

How in the world do you get from my answer (second line) to the third line? It doesn't even make algebraic sense. I will be going to office hours tomorrow, but if this is my mistake I don't want to bother her. I just don't see it...

Comment: Factor out $(x+2)^2$ from each term.

Comment: Thank You!! sorry i'm stupid

Comment: how do I give you a thumbs up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x+2)=a$ and $3x=b$.

Thus, $3x(x+2)^2+(x+2)^3=ba^2+a^3=a^2(b+a)$ Then, back substitute to verify that our expressions are equal.

Overall, we factored out a common factor of $(x+2)^2$ from each term in the expression.

Comment: Glad I could help you